# Spring/Tomcat closes the connection on exception

Tags: spring, tomcat

Recently I was debugging a problem that a client reported when they were stress-testing a spring application running in tomcat. They ran the tests, but most of the requests immediately resulted in an exception, causing a `500` response code.

At some point the client was no longer able to open new connections because the ephemeral port range was exhausted - all ports were in a `TIME_WAIT` state. The reason appears to be that when an exception occurs the connection is closed by either spring or tomcat.

I created a simple spring boot 2.7.6 application with a single controller, with two endpoints - `/5xx` which throws ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR), and `/4xx`
to throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).

After requesting these endpoints, the response contains a `Connection: close` header, and looking at the local ports with `ss` the ports in `TIME_WAIT` get increased.

Further, requesting an endpoint that doesn't exist - doesn't close the connection and simply returns 404.

When I switched to undertow, instead of tomcat - the connection wasn't closed for all endpoints.

When I switched to spring boot 3 and tomcat - the connection isn't closed as well for all three endpoints.

So, my questions are:

- What is the correct behavior? I'm thinking that the connection shouldn't be closed.
- Does anyone know if this is a spring or tomcat feature and is there a configuration for this?

**EDIT #1**:

OS details:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Linux 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024   60999

Tomcat:

- embedded tomcat v9.0.69 with default configuration provided by spring boot
- the situation improves by increasing `maxConnections` to 30000 (default is 10000)

Comment: Can you please share the details of OS on which these tests were run? Also would be helpful if you can please share server.xml config for Tomcat.

Comment: @vish213 I edited the question with some details, let me know if you need anything else.